# Expansion for Partial Fractions for $(3-2x)/(x^2+6x+9)$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I'm trying to expand $(3-2x)/(x^2+6x+9)$ into partial fractions to integrate.
I'm doing $$(3-2x)/((x+3)^2)=A/(x+3)+B(x+3)^2$$

$$(A(x+3)+B)/((x+3)^2)=3-2x$$

for x=0:$$(3A+B)/9=3$$

for x=1: $$(4A+B)/16=1$$

Giving the expansion of $-11/(x+3)+60/((x+3)^2)$

when it should be: $-2/(x+3)+9/((x+3)^2)$

How would I get the -2 and the 9 for the A and B?

Comment: It must be some algebraic mistake...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want: $$\frac{A(x+3)+B}{(x+3)^2}=\frac{3-2x}{(x+3)^2}$$ You lost the denominator on the right hand side.

Much, then, to solve: $$A(x+3)+B = 3-2x$$